# Is Ardent Censer still viable during late game?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to know if Ardent Censer IS viable for supports during late games considering:

- **Abilities/Skills** :

  Some supports benefit their team a lot, some may benefit his own a lot. I'm talking about AoE shields/heals that can really  take advantage of it but in exchange for other items.
- **Situations**

  If your team is much of an AD-based and the team has at least 2 AP, will AC be useful as a Solari does? Will AC + AP Stack (for better heal/shield)/ Tank items (if Alistar/Leona) be better?
- **Value of other (Support/Situational) Items**

  Is the buff really that useful considering that in late game, tanks are REAL tanks with their Omen all over their body, as well as Thornmail/Frozen Heart? Also, if ASPD is useful for AD damagers, why not use Zeke's Herald instead?

I just love the + movement speed items without being useless to my team so I'm thinking if it's worth building in decent elo ranked games .

Comment: Not a full answer, but if the ADC gets only a single AS item and has no natural AS buffs it could still be useful if you are a champion like Janna who can constantly shield with 40% cdr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually A pretty decent Item during any stage of the game. Similar to ohmwrecker it's not bad but heavily underused and very situational.

Now In the lategame it somehow loses a bit of its potential, however it can still be great for objectives like Baron, Dragon or Turrets. Especially on Chapions with AOE Heals/Shields like Karma, Janna or Alistar.

But should you buy it all the time? **No**.

It's really good if you can grab one early in the game on champions like Janna or Sona but if you haven't gotten it by 25-30 minutes you should probably go for more Tankiness instead of the Censer. Maybe if you go Full AP or if you are just trolling around you can still pick it up later in the game but there are definitely items that will show a bigger benefit for your team (Randuins/Locket etc).

Comment: Thresh's lantern isn't AoE any longer. Just him and one other.

Comment: @maxywb oups didn't really notice that patch... I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't build it except towards the end of your build order.  Wards, basic survivability (for you and your carries) are much more important than a small buff like Censure provides.